# Min Partition by with Case When

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partition

I have a table that looks like below:

```
      col1     user        Product    Ranking_Output  
2019-11-30      123              A                 1  
2019-12-01      123              B                 2
2019-12-11      123              B                 3
```

For Product = 'B', how do I find the minimum `ranking_output` by user?

I tried a minimum partition by like below but got the following result:

`CASE WHEN PRODUCT LIKE '%B%' THEN MIN(Ranking_Output) OVER (PARTITION BY User) ELSE 1 END MIN_DETECTOR`

```
      col1     user        Product    Ranking_Output     Actual Output   
2019-11-30      123              A                 1                 1    
2019-12-01      123              B                 2                 1     
2019-12-11      123              B                 3                 1
```

I want to avoid using a "where" clause because this is part of a bigger table and want to have the output look like below:

```
      col1     user        Product    Ranking_Output     Desired Output
2019-11-30      123              A                 1           1
2019-12-01      123              B                 2           2
2019-12-11      123              B                 3           2
```

Comment: Hi, what database do you use ? Please tag it. Thanks!

Comment: just tagged it @VBoka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(sorry, didn't notice the DB you're using .. I work off Oracle .. so syntax might not match yours .. )

The issue you're having, is the analytical is not "honoring" the case .. that is .. it calculates the analytic despite the case ... then displays the results of the analytic based on your case.

[edit] that didn't sound as clear as I wanted .. let's try this:
The query is **calculating** your analytical function first ... then it handles the case ... so the analytical function is using ALL rows for it's calculation, but then only displaying on the B values you wanted.
[/edit]

To have it calculate more accurately to what you want, include the product in your partition :

```
  CASE WHEN PRODUCT LIKE '%B%' 
        THEN MIN(Ranking_Output) OVER (PARTITION BY cuser,product) 
     ELSE 1 
     END MIN_DETECTOR
```

so this: (FYI I used "cuser" as column, since "user" is reserved word .. )

```
  with w_data as (
        select '2019-11-30'  col1, 123  cuser, 'A'  product, 1  ranking_output from dual union all
        select '2019-12-01'  col1, 123  cuser, 'B'  product, 2  ranking_output from dual union all
        select '2019-12-11'  col1, 123  cuser, 'B'  product, 3  ranking_output from dual 
     )
  select col1, cuser, product, ranking_output,
        CASE WHEN PRODUCT LIKE '%B%' 
              THEN MIN(Ranking_Output) OVER (PARTITION BY cuser,product) 
           ELSE 1 
           END MIN_DETECTOR
  from w_data
  /
```

produces this output:

```
  COL1            CUSER P RANKING_OUTPUT MIN_DETECTOR
  ---------- ---------- - -------------- ------------
  2019-11-30        123 A              1            1
  2019-12-11        123 B              3            2
  2019-12-01        123 B              2            2

  3 rows selected.
```

Comment: thank you this worked! Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Add `PRODUCT` to your `PARTITION BY`

```
CASE
    WHEN PRODUCT LIKE '%B%'
        THEN MIN(Ranking_Output) OVER (PARTITION BY User, Product)
    ELSE 1
END MIN_DETECTOR
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the sum of the non-B values before each row.  If so:

```
(case when product like '%B%'
      then sum(case when product not like '%B%' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user order by col_1)
      else 1
 end)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, my goal is to get the minimum for product b only. Everything else will be labeled as 1. Does this cover that? Testing now.

Comment: @nak5120 . . . I think that is what this query does.